# Rewrite GET color variation variable in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

I was trying all the solutions I could find on StackOverflow, but still was unable to make it work. So, my last hope is to ask this question directly.

So, I have a wordpress/woocommerce shop with variable products that have colors. As you probably know, you can access specific variations with a GET variable. For example:

https://example.com/shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/?attribute_pa_product-color=chestnut-burnished

"chestnut-burnished" is, of course, dynamic value as there are plenty of other colors.

What I would like to do is to be able to access this variation by entering this URL instead:

https://example.com/shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/chestnut-burnished/

I've been trying lots of rewrite rules, but none seem to be working. If I input the URL above I always get a 404 page instead of the single product color variation one.

I guess this, has something to do with the existing Wordpress rule, which is in root .htaccess and makes pretty links. Here's the full .htaccess file that I have:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^summer\-sale/ /mens-shoes-sale/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^summer\-sale /mens-shoes-sale/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/10\-most\-popular\-mens\-classic\-shoes/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/10\-most\-popular\-mens\-classic\-shoes/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/how\-to\-care\-for\-your\-leather\-shoes/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/how\-to\-care\-for\-your\-leather\-shoes/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/6\-classic\-shoes\-every\-man\-should\-own/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/6\-classic\-shoes\-every\-man\-should\-own/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/how\-to\-choose\-the\-right\-black\-tie\-tuxedo\-shoes/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/how\-to\-choose\-the\-right\-black\-tie\-tuxedo\-shoes/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/5\-british\-made\-shoes\-worn\-by\-movie\-characters/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/5\-british\-made\-shoes\-worn\-by\-movie\-characters/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/6\-most\-popular\-mens\-brogue\-shoe\-styles/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/6\-most\-popular\-mens\-brogue\-shoe\-styles/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/shoes/5\-benefits\-of\-a\-goodyear\-welted\-shoes/$ /blog/mens\-shoes/5\-benefits\-of\-a\-goodyear\-welted\-shoes/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mens-shoes/loake/?$ /mens-shoes/?brand=loake&orderby=menu_order [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mens-shoes/carlos-santos/?$ /mens-shoes/?brand=carlos-santos&orderby=menu_order [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mens-shoes/trickers/?$ /mens-shoes/?brand=trickers&orderby=menu_order [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post_type\=product&p\=5979$
RewriteRule ^$ /shoe-care/brushes/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/([^/]+)/?$ /shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/?attribute_pa_product-color=$1 [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp\-content/+debug\.log$
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <Files "debug.log">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    </Files>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any chance you could help me?

Comment: If you don't want to have answers for things you have already tried, you could providing an examples of what didn't work so far.

Comment: The answer by arkascha below, for example, is not working. I get 404. I believe this has something to do with the wordpress itself and its permalink structure.

Comment: Perhaps try taking a look at this WordPress support article about using query string as URL parameters, essentially that is what you are trying to do. You m ay have to do some fiddling with the scripts but maybe that will help. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/url-rewrite-multiple-parameters-templates-dynamic-path-parameter-placement/

Answer (score 1):

This would be the required rewriting rule when implemented on top level:

```
RewriteRule ^/?shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/([^/]+)/?$ /shop/mens-shoes/derby-shoes/trickers-wiltshire-leather-derby-shoes/?attribute_pa_product-color=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You should prefer to implement such a rule in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: you are using a cheap hosting provider), then you can implement it in a *distributed* configuration file, typically called ".htaccess". That file would have to be placed in the root folder of your http host (`DOCUMENT_ROOT`).

Most likely there already is such a file which already contains rules, so you need to integrate this one. Keep in mind that the order of processing those rules is top to bottom and the order is relevant. Typically you'd have to implement such an exception rule further up, above the generic rules generated by your framework.

It might also be possible to implement such a rule further down in the folder hierarchy. But that depends on your actual setup you did not share with us.

Also you might want to implement a more generic rule which applies to multiple products instead of just a specific on. But again: there isn't enough information in the question to give a straight forward answer to that.

---

You wrote that you already tried all existing answers to this question you found here. And I assume you also read into the documentation of apache's rewriting module, since it offers good explanations and great examples.

Since you failed to get things to work it might well be that there is a general miss understanding here. But once more this is just a guess due to the lack of detailed information in the question.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to .htaccess file.
And yes, I would like to have a generic rule that would apply to all of the products that have the color attribute.
My first time posting, sorry for the missing info.

Comment: Sure, all fine. Then I suggest you start with implementing a rule for this specific case. If you get that to work, then you can go on and generalize that in a second step.

Comment: I have implemented this rule and I get a 404 page.
Was trying to access https://example.com/shop/mens-shoes/oxford-shoes/trickers-regent-leather-toe-cap-oxford-shoes/black/

Comment: So you will need to add more details describing your setup to the question above. There is an "edit" link below it, use it. _Where_ did you implement that rule. Please add your actual implementation. What does your http server's error and access logs contain as a result to a test request? Are there _other_ rules already implemented? Anything else that might be of interest?

Comment: I have implemented it in the .htaccess file, exactly as you have written. Error log shows 404. There are other rules implemented in the .htaccess file but they are not interfering with this case.

Comment: In _which_ ".htaccess" file? What rule have you implemented _exactly_ ? What _other_ rules? Why did you not add that file to the question? What about the log file entries?

Comment: In root .htaccess. I have added the main rule that Wordpress ads itself to make pretty links to my original post. I can't seem to find the log files.

Comment: You are implementing a web service, a _commercial_ web service, and you are not aware of the log files your http server writes? How did you implement your setup without ever taking a look into especially the error log file?

Comment: And, one last time: please post the _full_ ".htaccess" while including the rule you implemented based on this answer.

Comment: Also important: did you make sure that you are not looking at a cached result when making test requests? How did you do that?

Comment: I don't have full access to the server. My FTP account allows me to view only public_html folder and what's inside it. The owner of the website has full access.

Comment: I have added the full .htaccess. I was testing via Chrome Developer tools with "disable cache" selected in Network tab.

Comment: There is no trace of any rule in that ".htaccess" file's content you posted that has anything to do with what this question is about.

Comment: Well, there is a rule that you've written. I just don't understand why it isn't working. And I think that it has to do with how Wordpress handles those URLs by rewriting them.